# Is there a way to backup deduplicated NTFS drive with rsync or other linux tool?

Tags: linux, ntfs, rsync, cifs, deduplication

Is there a Linux way or a tool that is aware of Windows Deduplication on NTFS?
Here I use rsync to sync files from a AD file server shares.
The shares are mounted, readonly, using mount.cifs on linux.

Because Linux is not aware of the deduplicated files it syncs all the copies.

I enabled the Deduplication service in Windows Server 2012 R2 because in a 2TB drive I had only 190GB free. After activating of deduplication (+- a week later) my free space went to 860GB

The shares are in and AD environment where various users from different rooms/sectors store data. They have the habit of making copies of the same file to another folder, which they consider backup. – tenshimsm 4 mins ago   edit

I am starting a "migration" to BTRFS. I will start using Snapper. But this require some changes. And as I need to sync those files to another disk to start testing snapshots etc.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Why would duplication matter if you mount the shares read only?

Comment: @Seth I had a WTF moment as well. I think he means "aware of de-duplication" while reading the share so every block gets read at most 1 time, even if it is referenced by multiple files. Any other way of interpreting that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Seth It does matter. Just giving information that i think could help. The problem is that as Linux is not aware of the deduplicated files every time rsync is run, it syncs all the copies of the same file.

Comment: I enabled the Deduplication service in Windows Server 2012 R2 because in a 2TB drive I had only 190GB free. After activating deduplication (+- a week later) my free space went to 860GB

Comment: Your question is poorly worded. That's why it's not clear why it matters. If you do have such a huge saving ... what on earth are you doing do have so many duplicate files? A share doesn't expose any information about deduplication so you won't be able to figure it by just reading the share. Why not use a FS with deduplication support for the Linux system as well?

Comment: @Seth The shares are in and AD environment where various users from different rooms/sectors store data. They have the habit of making copies of the same file to another folder, which they consider backup.

Comment: @Seth I am starting a "migration" to BTRFS. I will start using Snapper. But this require some changes. And as I need to sync those files to another disk to start testing snapshots etc.

Comment: @Seth is my question that poor? Is that so hard to understand?

Comment: Your initial question didn't make it clear which side you want to be deduplication aware and/or why you'd want your Linux side to be aware of Windows Deduplication. Especially since you're using `rsync` which is not. It wasn't poor like some others are but lacking detail to enable people to quickly grasp what you want to do and to enable people to suggest additional approaches that might work while not being that straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to perform backups without wasting space on duplicate files, then consider backing up to another deduplicated drive on another server (Windows or Linux).  I don't know of any deduplication-aware backup apps... they generally run inside the OS and see the files presented by the OS.  You might also consider using Windows Links instead of copies of the file.  Or, if there's whole directories that are identical, consider putting them in C:\SharedFiles or C:\Users\Public .

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any backup tools that are "deduplication aware."  However, due to how deduplication works, I doubt there would be any.  Perhaps it is possible that backup software has advanced since I last looked.

However, it is possible to do optimized backups of deduplicated volumes.  This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh769304(v=vs.85).aspx) describes in detail.  In essence, your backup tool is doing incremental backups.  By backing up only changed files since the last backup, your tool is not backing up new files with its deduplicated chunks.